# Dagger Hilt Error Execution failed for task How can I solve this issue?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

the error I am getting is Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

```
      @Module
      @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
      object AppModule {

      @Provides
      @Singleton
      fun providesApiService() : ApiService =
         Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(ApiService::class.java)

      }
```